# SelectManyCheckbox value not updating on xhtml(frontend) though updates in bean

Tags: jsf

I have two selectManyCheckbox one for source id and other for destination id, based on the source value change the destination values should be changed(populated) ... I have tried using valuechangelistener and ajax function but both the processes have not been successful .. Whenever I change Source values, Desination values stay the same... However if after changing the source values, I click the Submit (commandbutton) the destination values are populated properly .. I have used update="@form" in the source selectMayCheckbox .. where am i going wrong?

Comment: In the duplicate question, just substitute "selectOneMenu" with "selectManyCheckbox" (or whatever "select(One|Many)Xxx") and the same answer applies.

Comment: Thanks ,got some hint to solve